# Вдруг он услышал чей-то призыв(,) и пошёл к Илию. Присоединительная ли это конструкция после запятой?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, запятые, сказуемые, пунктуация

Снова та же ситуация: два сказуемых (почти нет сомнений, что однородных) и между ними союз **и**. У автора перед союзом стоит запятая. Хочется её сохранить, но четкой аргументации нет. Опять объяснять присоединительным характером союза?
Текст идет так: *Однажды Самуил **ночевал** в храме **и спал**. Вдруг он **услышал** чей-то призыв, **и пошёл** к Илию.* Чёрным выделено для сравнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вдруг он услышал чей-то призыв, и пошёл к Илию.**

Скорее всего, **запятая здесь не нужна.** А история такая: http://voskresnaya-shkola.ru/uroki-dlya-malyshej/biblejskij-urok-samuil.html

Вдруг послышался голос, который звал: «Самуил, Самуил!» Маленький Самуил проснулся. **Он вскочил с постели и побежал к Илию.** Я здесь, Илий, что ты хочешь сказать мне? Я слышал, как ты звал меня».  «Я не звал тебя, Самуил. Иди ложись в свою кровать». Самуил пошел, лег в свою мягкую теплую постель, укрылся одеялом до самого подбородка и опять крепко уснул.  Но голос позвал опять: «Самуил, Самуил!» Самуил вскочил с постели и снова пошел к Илию.

**Как можно объяснить авторскую запятую** и считать союз присоединительным?  Можно предположить, что пауза связана с тем, что Самуил не знал, кто его зовет, но почему-то решил, что это Илия.